# Calculating difference between two date-times in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

**Problem Summary**

I have two strings in the form *YYYY-MM-DD:hh:mm:ss* and I would like to calculate the time difference between them. For example, the difference between *2021-10-01:03:44:34* and *2021-10-01:03:44:54*, should be *20* seconds. However, the result I get is *0*.

**Code**

I have tried the following:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using timestamp = time_t;

auto StringToTimestamp(const string& timeString) -> timestamp {
  tm tm {};
  stringstream ssBuffer(timeString);
  ssBuffer >> get_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d:%H:%M:%S");
 
  cout << tm.tm_year << " " << tm.tm_mon << " " << tm.tm_mday << " "
       << tm.tm_hour << " "<< tm.tm_min  << " " << tm.tm_sec  << " " << endl;

  return  mktime(&tm);
}

int main() {
  string beg = {"2021-10-01:03:44:34"s};
  string end = {"2021-10-01:03:44:54"s};

  timestamp begTm = StringToTimestamp(beg);
  timestamp endTm = StringToTimestamp(end);

  double diff = difftime(endTm, begTm);
  cout << "Time difference is " << diff << endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
121 0 0 0 0 0 
121 0 0 0 0 0 
Time difference is 0
```

**Expected Output**

```
2021 10 01 03 44 34 
2021 10 01 03 04 54 
Time difference is 20
```

Why is the output as such? How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

I changed this line `"%Y-%b-%d:%H:%M:%S"` to `"%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S"` and now the output is

```
121 9 1 3 44 34 
121 9 1 3 44 54 
Time difference is 20
```

Why are the year and month "incorrect"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the conversion specifier`%b` to get the month but it should be `%m`:

```
ssBuffer >> get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S");
```

- `%b` - parses the month name, either full or abbreviated, e.g. **Oct** (**non-numeric**)
- `%m` - parses the month **as a decimal number** (range [01,12]), leading zeroes permitted but not required

The year and month are correct. 121 is the number of years since 1900 and 9 is the month, zero-based [0,11], which is what's specified for [`std::tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm).

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at the edit, the month is 9 instead of 10. Why is that?

Comment: @AngelosFr I added that to the answer. It parses the month number 10, but stores it in the `std::tm` as 9.